# Check isValidDate in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm currently using a JavaScript function to check if a given string represents a valid date. However, I've encountered a problem where certain non-date strings, like "SA-0001" or simple numbers inside strings like "1", are erroneously being identified as valid dates.

```
function isValidDate(val) {
    if (typeof val === 'number') {
        return false;
    }
    const str = new Date(val);
    if (str != 'Invalid Date') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the incoming string, the format for valid date string varies and is not fixed, such as 'yyyy-mm-dd', and I aim to avoid restricting the backend to a specific format. How can I accurately determine if a given value represents a valid date without imposing a fixed format constraint?

Ex.

- Input: '1999-01-01' Expected result: true
- Input: '01-01-1999' Expected result: true
- Input: '01-1999-01' Expected result: true
- Input: 'Fri Mar 15 2024 18:19:30' Expected result: true
- Input: '01-01' Expected result: false
- Input: '01' Expected result: false
- Input: 'sa-0001' Expected result: false

Comment: A new Date instance will never be equal to the string `"Invalid Date"`.  You can use `new Date(val).toString()` instead.

Comment: Also that's not a good way to check validity anyway. A string that the browser is willing to recognize as a date may be *valid*, but it may be interpreted in an unexpected way that does not correspond to what the user who typed the date into  an `<input>` field intended.

Comment: The format for the valid string varies based on what? You need to provide it (but it can change dependant on something, like the users locale) because otherwise how would you know if `01/08/2024` is 1st August 2024 or 8th January 2024? As for how to provide it -- better to use a date lib like https://date-fns.org/ or https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format (many others). These libs have much more controlled parsing and the problem of weird results will be gone.

Comment: try `new Date('2024-04-31')`

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev ... yeah, that and its kind are a classic.

Comment: It is not enough to provide examples of what you consider valid date representations, as that leaves unclear what else would be valid or not valid. For instance, what about `Mar 15 124` or `Vrij 15 Maart 2024 18:19:30` or `15'03'2024` or `15.24.03` or `15th of March 2024` or `15 Sept. 2024, 12h10` or ...

Comment: For things like this, I like to step back and consider what's most important. Here that might be: how do false positives/negatives affect strings with (or without) dates in them in the context of my application. If you design around the fact that some dates may not be automatically interpreted correctly, you can design a mechanism with which to "correct" dates the program got tripped up on (or things that weren't dates to begin with). It's more of a heuristic approach, but will get the job done with increasing accuracy and reduced input over time.

Comment: (Note that 'over time' bit: that can come about from something as simple as you adding a check for another date format, or something complex like an expanding set of regex rules or some other ML approach).